# loop ends up pushing thousands of objects into array unintentionally

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an object that has a structure like this:

```
var costByScn = [
  {
    "key": "K1204", 
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Both", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": "1420070400000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          ...
        ]
      }, 
      ...
    ]
  }, 
  {
    "key": "tere", 
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "On-Prem", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": "1438387200000", 
            "values": 1602.24390394729
          }, 
          ...
        ]
      }, 
      ...
    ]
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is to find the min and max datetime value, and then go through all of the arrays and essentially "sync" them together.

So if my min is 1420070400000 and my max is 1575158400000 (increment by month), it should create any missing pairs with a `values` of 0.

Right now, I've essentially have this with a bunch of loops to try to do this (I'd be curious if there is a more efficient way of doing this as well).

What I'm trying to do now is create and arrary `dtRng` of timestamps in milliseconds incremented by month between `dtMin` and `dtMax`, and then make sure each of those increments has an object in the array.

I think I'm close, but now at this part `scnFtprntDates.values.push({key: dtRng[q], values: 0})`...it seems to be pushing in thousands of new objects into the array and keeps crashing the browser and I can't seem to figure out why. It looks like an infinite loop some where but can't figure out what it is as console log shows this for:

```
dtMin: 1420070400000
dtMax: 1575158400000 
dtRng: [1420070400000, 1422748800000, 1425168000000, 1427842800000, 1430434800000, 1433113200000, 1435705200000, 1438383600000, 1441062000000, 1443654000000, 1446332400000, 1448928000000, 1451606400000, 1454284800000, 1456790400000, 1459465200000, 1462057200000, 1464735600000, 1467327600000, 1470006000000, 1472684400000, 1475276400000, 1477954800000, 1480550400000, 1483228800000, 1485907200000, 1488326400000, 1491001200000, 1493593200000, 1496271600000, 1498863600000, 1501542000000, 1504220400000, 1506812400000, 1509490800000, 1512086400000, 1514764800000, 1517443200000, 1519862400000, 1522537200000, 1525129200000, 1527807600000, 1530399600000, 1533078000000, 1535756400000, 1538348400000, 1541026800000, 1543622400000, 1546300800000, 1548979200000, 1551398400000, 1554073200000, 1556665200000, 1559343600000, 1561935600000, 1564614000000, 1567292400000, 1569884400000, 1572562800000, 1575158400000]
```

here is my code:

```
var scn = costByScn

for (var i=0; i<scn.length; i++) {

    var dtMax = 0;
    var dtMin = 1923273544000;


    var scnFtprnt = scn[i];

    console.log("scnftprnt: ", scnFtprnt);

    console.log("scnftprnt: ", scnFtprnt.values.length);

    for (j=0; j<scnFtprnt.values.length; j++) {

        var scnFtprntDates = scnFtprnt.values[j];

        for (var q=0; q<scnFtprntDates.values.length; q++) {

            var scnFtprntDt = scnFtprntDates.values[q].key

            if (dtMax < scnFtprntDt) {

                dtMax = scnFtprntDt
            }

            if (dtMin > scnFtprntDt) {

                dtMin = scnFtprntDt 
            }


        }

    }

   var dtRng = []

    console.log("dtmin: ", dtMin);
   console.log("dtmax: ", dtMax);

    var offset = 5*60*60000

    dtMin = new Date(+dtMin + offset);
    dtMax = new Date(+dtMax + offset);

   console.log("dtmin: ", dtMin);
   console.log("dtmax: ", dtMax);

   while (dtMin <= dtMax) {

       dtRng.push(dtMin.getTime() - offset);

       dtMin = new Date(new Date(dtMin).setMonth(dtMin.getMonth()+1));

   }

    console.log("dt rng:", dtRng);

    console.log("dt rng:", dtRng.length);

    for (l=0; l<scnFtprnt.values.length; l++) {

        console.log("scnftprn: ", scnFtprnt.values[l]);

        var scnFtprntDates = scnFtprnt.values[l];

        if (scnFtprntDates.values.isArray) { console.log("is array")} else { console.log(scnFtprntDates.values.isArray)}

        console.log("array2: ", scnFtprntDates.values)

        for (var q=0; dtRng.length; q++) {

            for (var z=0; z<scnFtprntDates.values.length; z++) {

                if (dtRng[q] == scnFtprntDates.values[z].key) {

                } else {
                    console.log("pushing");
                    scnFtprntDates.values.push({key: dtRng[q], values: 0})

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Essentially, the key in each object in key.values.values should match one of the values in the array `dtRng`. Let says value `1483228800000` in the `dtRng` array wasn't found in `key` of key.values.values array of objects, it should add an object like `{key: 1483228800000, values: 0}` to that array...

---EDIT----

I tried to the part where it loops and finds missing keys and pushes them into the array like this:

```
var lngth = scnFtprntDates.values.length

for (var q=0; q<dtRng.length; q++) {

    for (var z=0; z<lngth; z++) {

        if (dtRng[q] == parseInt(scnFtprntDates.values[z].key)) {
            break;
        } else {
            console.log("pushing")
            scnFtprntDates.values.push({key: dtRng[q], values: 0})

        }

    }
}
```

but them I get this result, it still seems to push in values (the ones of `values: 0`) it already has in the array...

```
[
  {
    "key": "Kallam 1204", 
    "values": [
      {
        "key": "Both", 
        "values": [
          {
            "key": "1420070400000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1422748800000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          }, 
          {
            "key": "1425168000000", 
            "values": 27927.7349421797
          },
          ...
          {
            "key": 1422748800000, 
            "values": 0
          }, 
          {
            "key": 1425168000000, 
            "values": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

here is a copy of the code and test data in jsfiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhrwv09p/1/

```js
var costByScn = [{
  "key": "K1204",
  "values": [{
    "key": "Both",
    "values": [{
      "key": "1420070400000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1422748800000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1425168000000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1427846400000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1430438400000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1433116800000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1435708800000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1438387200000",
      "values": 27927.734942179697
    }, {
      "key": "1441065600000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1443657600000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1446336000000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1448928000000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1451606400000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1454284800000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1456790400000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1459468800000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1462060800000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1464739200000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1467331200000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1470009600000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1472688000000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1475280000000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1477958400000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1480550400000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1483228800000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1485907200000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1488326400000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }]
  }, {
    "key": "Cloud",
    "values": [{
      "key": "1420070400000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1422748800000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1425168000000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1427846400000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1430438400000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1433116800000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1435708800000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1438387200000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1441065600000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1443657600000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1446336000000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1448928000000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1451606400000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1454284800000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1456790400000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1459468800000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1462060800000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1464739200000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1467331200000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1470009600000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1472688000000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1475280000000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1477958400000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1480550400000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1483228800000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1485907200000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1488326400000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1491004800000",
      "values": 375564.8638
    }, {
      "key": "1493596800000",
      "values": 375564.8638
    }, {
      "key": "1496275200000",
      "values": 375564.8638
    }, {
      "key": "1498867200000",
      "values": 375564.86380000005
    }, {
      "key": "1501545600000",
      "values": 375564.86380000005
    }, {
      "key": "1504224000000",
      "values": 375564.86380000005
    }, {
      "key": "1506816000000",
      "values": 375564.8638
    }, {
      "key": "1509494400000",
      "values": 375564.86380000005
    }, {
      "key": "1512086400000",
      "values": 375564.86380000005
    }, {
      "key": "1514764800000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }, {
      "key": "1517443200000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1519862400000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1522540800000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }, {
      "key": "1525132800000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1527811200000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1530403200000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1533081600000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }, {
      "key": "1535760000000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1538352000000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1541030400000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1543622400000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1546300800000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1548979200000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1551398400000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1554076800000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1556668800000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1559347200000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1561939200000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }, {
      "key": "1564617600000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1567296000000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }, {
      "key": "1569888000000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }, {
      "key": "1572566400000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1575158400000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }]
  }]
}]


var scn = costByScn

for (var i = 0; i < scn.length; i++) {

  var dtMax = 0;
  var dtMin = 1923273544000;


  var scnFtprnt = scn[i];

  console.log("scnftprnt: ", scnFtprnt);

  console.log("scnftprnt: ", scnFtprnt.values.length);

  for (j = 0; j < scnFtprnt.values.length; j++) {

    var scnFtprntDates = scnFtprnt.values[j];

    for (var q = 0; q < scnFtprntDates.values.length; q++) {

      var scnFtprntDt = scnFtprntDates.values[q].key

      if (dtMax < scnFtprntDt) {

        dtMax = scnFtprntDt
      }

      if (dtMin > scnFtprntDt) {

        dtMin = scnFtprntDt
      }


    }

  }

  var dtRng = []

  console.log("dtmin: ", dtMin);
  console.log("dtmax: ", dtMax);

  var offset = 5 * 60 * 60000

  dtMin = new Date(+dtMin + offset);
  dtMax = new Date(+dtMax + offset);

  console.log("dtmin: ", dtMin);
  console.log("dtmax: ", dtMax);

  while (dtMin <= dtMax) {

    dtRng.push(dtMin.getTime() - offset);

    dtMin = new Date(new Date(dtMin).setMonth(dtMin.getMonth() + 1));

  }

  console.log("dt rng:", dtRng);

  console.log("dt rng:", dtRng[0]);

                    for (l=0; l<scnFtprnt.values.length; l++) {
                        
                        console.log("scnftprn: ", scnFtprnt.values[l]);
                        
                        var scnFtprntDates = scnFtprnt.values[l];
                        var scn2 = scnFtprntDates.values
                        
                        if (scn2.isArray) { console.log("is array")} else { console.log("is not array")}
                        
                        console.log("array2: ", scnFtprntDates.values)
                        
                        var lngth = scnFtprntDates.values.length
                        
                        for (var q=0; q<dtRng.length; q++) {
                            console.log("part1: ", dtRng[q].toString());
                            if (_.some([scn2], ["key", dtRng[q]])) {
                                
                                
                                
                            } else {
                                
                                scn2.push({key: dtRng[q], values: 0})
                                
                            }
                            
                        }

                    }

}





console.log("data2: ", JSON.stringify(scn));
```

Comment: _"Right now, I've essentially have this with a bunch of loops to try to do this but is there a more efficient way of doing this as well?"_ You could use [Lodash](https://lodash.com)

Comment: You have nested arrays and objects here and it's not really clear what you want the result to look like. Could you provide a clear before & after example?

Comment: @JLRishe I made an edit at the end to try and describe that...

Comment: Your limit on your innermost `for` loop is on `scnFtprntDates.values.length`, but you're also pushing values into that array at the same time, essentially always increasing the number of things the `for` loop is iterating over. Better to grab the length before the `for` loops in a variable and use that to limit the loop.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, I gave that a shot but still getting the same result as before it seems...

Comment: Well, it looks like the loop terminates in this case, whereas before it crashed the browser, so that's progress, right? The problem here is that you have keys that are strings, and you're adding keys that are numbers. If you're getting the data with the keys as strings, make `dtRng` hold strings instead. You might consider putting your code (including the test data) into a Stack Snippet (in the editor, icon is `<>` in a page) so that it's easier for people to replicate.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, not quite sure how to use Stack Snippet, but here is a jsfiddle of it though....https://jsfiddle.net/Lhrwv09p/1/

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, getting closer, I'm trying to use lodash to see if the value its looping through in `dtRng` array is contained in the array of objects but it doesn't seem to find them even though they are there...updated the fiddle and the stack snippet...

Answer (score 0):

So, I did see that you had made some progress with lodash, but I've found that a lot of the things lodash does are available in plain old JavaScript if you're willing to be a bit more verbose. Below I've also added sorting to the end result so that it's easier to see where the missing values have been filled in.

I've updated the `push` into `dtRng` to take the value as a string, as I was assuming that you were getting the data from a service. That makes it easier to do the next part.

The `scn2.some(function (item) { return item.key === dtRng[q]; })` part is basically equivalent to the lodash function you had in your updated snippet.

I change the result of finding a duplicate to `continue` so that it moves on to the next item in the array rather than `break`ing out of the `for` loop.

```js
var sorter = function (a, b) {
  return a.key === b.key ? 0 : a.key > b.key ? 1 : -1;
}
var costByScn = [{
  "key": "K1204",
  "values": [{
    "key": "Both",
    "values": [{
      "key": "1420070400000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1422748800000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1425168000000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1427846400000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1430438400000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1433116800000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1435708800000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1438387200000",
      "values": 27927.734942179697
    }, {
      "key": "1441065600000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1443657600000",
      "values": 27927.7349421797
    }, {
      "key": "1446336000000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1448928000000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1451606400000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1454284800000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1456790400000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1459468800000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1462060800000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1464739200000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1467331200000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1470009600000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1472688000000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1475280000000",
      "values": 36929.2001421797
    }, {
      "key": "1477958400000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1480550400000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1483228800000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1485907200000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }, {
      "key": "1488326400000",
      "values": 36929.200142179696
    }]
  }, {
    "key": "Cloud",
    "values": [{
      "key": "1420070400000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1422748800000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1425168000000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1427846400000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1430438400000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1433116800000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1435708800000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1438387200000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1441065600000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1443657600000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1446336000000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1448928000000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1451606400000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1454284800000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1456790400000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1459468800000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1462060800000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1464739200000",
      "values": 289819.9054
    }, {
      "key": "1467331200000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1470009600000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1472688000000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1475280000000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1477958400000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1480550400000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1483228800000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1485907200000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1488326400000",
      "values": 366563.39859999996
    }, {
      "key": "1491004800000",
      "values": 375564.8638
    }, {
      "key": "1493596800000",
      "values": 375564.8638
    }, {
      "key": "1496275200000",
      "values": 375564.8638
    }, {
      "key": "1498867200000",
      "values": 375564.86380000005
    }, {
      "key": "1501545600000",
      "values": 375564.86380000005
    }, {
      "key": "1504224000000",
      "values": 375564.86380000005
    }, {
      "key": "1506816000000",
      "values": 375564.8638
    }, {
      "key": "1509494400000",
      "values": 375564.86380000005
    }, {
      "key": "1512086400000",
      "values": 375564.86380000005
    }, {
      "key": "1514764800000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }, {
      "key": "1517443200000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1519862400000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1522540800000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }, {
      "key": "1525132800000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1527811200000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1530403200000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1533081600000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }, {
      "key": "1535760000000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1538352000000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1541030400000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1543622400000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1546300800000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1548979200000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1551398400000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1554076800000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1556668800000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1559347200000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1561939200000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }, {
      "key": "1564617600000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1567296000000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }, {
      "key": "1569888000000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }, {
      "key": "1572566400000",
      "values": 499244.1814
    }, {
      "key": "1575158400000",
      "values": 499244.18139999994
    }]
  }]
}]


var scn = costByScn

for (var i = 0; i < scn.length; i++) {

  var dtMax = 0;
  var dtMin = 1923273544000;


  var scnFtprnt = scn[i];

  for (j = 0; j < scnFtprnt.values.length; j++) {

    var scnFtprntDates = scnFtprnt.values[j];

    for (var q = 0; q < scnFtprntDates.values.length; q++) {

      var scnFtprntDt = scnFtprntDates.values[q].key

      if (dtMax < scnFtprntDt) {

        dtMax = scnFtprntDt
      }

      if (dtMin > scnFtprntDt) {

        dtMin = scnFtprntDt
      }


    }

  }

  var dtRng = []

  var offset = 5 * 60 * 60000

  dtMin = new Date(+dtMin + offset);
  dtMax = new Date(+dtMax + offset);

  while (dtMin <= dtMax) {

    dtRng.push(String(dtMin.getTime() - offset));

    dtMin = new Date(new Date(dtMin).setMonth(dtMin.getMonth() + 1));

  }

  for (l = 0; l < scnFtprnt.values.length; l++) {

    var scnFtprntDates = scnFtprnt.values[l];
    var scn2 = scnFtprntDates.values

    var lngth = scnFtprntDates.values.length

    for (var q = 0; q < dtRng.length; q++) {
      if (scn2.some(function (item) { return item.key === dtRng[q]; })) { 
        continue; 
      } else {
        scn2.push({
          key: dtRng[q],
          values: 0
        })

      }

    }

    scn2.sort(sorter);
    
    scnFtprnt.values[l] = scn2;
  }

}

scn.sort(sorter);


console.log("data2: ", JSON.stringify(scn));
```